# Arc-theme weird behaviour

Tags: themes

I’ve experienced this issue after some upgrades, I’m running Ubuntu 16.10, I tried to follow all the guides on that sites without success, deleted and reinstalled many times, nothing happened. As you can see I get a strange launcher, strange nautilus and menus are strange too, they are just very little writes:

[image]

This is what it should look like:

[image]

On the launcher there shouldn't be the squares behind the icons and also the navigator that says Recents, Home, Documents etc. should be grey and blue and should have a greater font. The same thing happens for the menus.

Comment: What's your question? Also, I don't understand what the issue is. I don't see any obvious ones on the screenshot. Could you please [edit] your question to 1) describe them and 2) include a picture that highlights them? Thanks.

Comment: Ok sorry i'll be more specific.

Comment: @Fantasma8 How did you install the theme?

Comment: @edwinksl I tried from the terminal, pasting the theme in /usr/src/themes, and following the manual installation here explained: https://github.com/horst3180/arc-theme
Always uninstalling it before trying a new one.

Comment: @Fantasma8 Did you try `sudo apt install arc-theme`?

Comment: @edwinksl Yes i did, but no luck. It all was perfect before i did a software update.

Comment: There are 3 issues: 1. You did not install the package from the Ubuntu repositories, remove whatever repositories and packages you have previously installed to get the arc theme. Update the package cache and reinstall from the repositories, this will fix the rendering issues in Nautilus. 2. The second screenshot is not from Unity, so Unity will not look like this. The white activity indicators are correct. 3. I cannot reproduce the shapes on the launcher icons. → Start with a new user profile or new installation of Ubuntu and provide a reproducible description. Voting to close this question.

Comment: @LiveWireBt Thank you, but i had the theme before and nautilus really looked like that, anyway i will try this way,thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In 16.10, arc-theme is included in the official repos. I saw similar effects when using the arc-theme from the OBS Repo; removing and reinstalling the official Ubuntu package fixed things. You could try removing the one you manually installed and reinstalling the official package.

### If you installed from the OBS Repo

If you installed from http://software.opensuse.org/download.html?project=home%3AHorst3180&package=arc-theme then you should have a file in `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/` named something like `arc-theme.list` and containing e.g. `deb http://download.opensuse.org/repositories/home:/Horst3180/xUbuntu_16.04/ /`. If so, remove and reinstall with

```
sudo rm /etc/apt/sources.list.d/arc-theme.list
sudo apt purge arc-theme
sudo apt update
sudo apt install arc-theme
```

### If you manually put the files in /usr/share/themes

Follow https://github.com/horst3180/arc-theme#uninstall and then

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install arc-theme
```